# get hyperlink column from sharepoint online by CSOM (C#)

Tags: development, csom, hyperlink, list-item

I run across an issue since yesterday when i use CSOM (c#) to get the URL and description fields from a Hyperlink field?

My first issue starts when i add a longer link to the hyperlink column.  It gives me an error with this message  `The value of this field may not contain more than 255 characters`. Is there a way out to fix this issue ?

I have tried to solve this problem  by creating `rich text column` and saving the url text as a link.  But i'm not sure if i can call this column as a URL (as a link) in my asp.net application.

My objective is to save all the links (that can trigger new item button for the selected lists) to specified list (in this case "linkst_to_Create") and to fetch for external application.

```
           foreach ( Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem listItem in items)
            {

                //  I got Title succesfully. 

                Label1.Text = "" + listItem["Title"];

              // testhyper is hyperlink column in the list

                HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = listItem["testhyper"].ToString();


            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listItem["testhyper"].ToString()` means you are casting your hyperlink column into `string` but you need to cast it into `FieldUrlValue` before using.

```
var hyperLink = (FieldUrlValue)listItem["testhyper"];

HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = hyperLink.Url;
```

There other columns like `FieldUserValue`, `FieldChoice` & `DateTime`, where you have to cast before getting values from these columns.

Comment: Now it works for URL field. As I mentioned on top hyperlink field can't contain more than 255 character. So I saved the link in richtext field as a link. But i got error when i call it as URL.

Comment: what is the type of **top hyperlink** field? is that a single line text field?

Comment: it is Multiple lines of text

Comment: Try it using `listItem["nameOfTheColumn"].ToString()`. It should return your link if you allow plain text only

Comment: NOw it works as charm !! thank you very much. you saved my day